# I want select all duplicate records from my table on the basis of student name and father name in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select student_name 
from thewings_clients_temp 
where concat(student_name,father_name) IN (
    select concat(student_name,father_name) from thewings_clients_temp group by student_name HAVING COUNT(concat(student_name,father_name)) > 1
)
```

Comment: I hope that your table have primary key? `SELECT DISTINCT t1.* FROM table t1 JOIN table t2 USING (student_name,father_name) WHERE t1.id <> t2.id;`

Comment: duplicate records are in the same table like this....

Comment: And what's your question about this? If you need help, please share the table structure, sample input data, the corresponding expected output, and more details about what is not working with the current query

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the students whose name is repeated more than once.

```
SELECT student_name,
       father_name,
       COUNT(*)
FROM thewings_clients_temp 
GROUP BY student_name, father_name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```